# Google Maps Distance API is undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the Google Maps Distance Matrix Service (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix).

I put this line in my `public/index.html`: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>`

In a react's js file, I can print `window.google` and see the global variable. I can also see that it has a function `window.google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()` to create the service. However, when I create that service with `var service = window.google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()`, `service` is `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: try `var service = new window.google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()` (the difference is the word **`new`** ) as per the documentation you linked to - you also don't need `window.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaromanda X pointed out, I missed the `new` keyword.

Full line is now: `var service = new window.google.map.DistanceMatrixService()`.